# SSMS browse filesystem - Cannot access the specifed path or file on the server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, ssms-2012

We have a database which have different logins and database users. If login is not sysadmin, SSMS gives an error like below

> C:\BackupShare
> Cannot access the specified path or file on the server. Verify that you have the necessary security privileges and that the path or file exists.
>
> If you know that the service account can access a specific file, type in the full path for the file in the File Name control in the Locate dialog box.

--

Concerns

- We should not login as windows login, use sql login instead
- We should not give sysadmin role to user.

I tried following ways but did not work

- Giving all permissions to folder for NETWORKService, MSSQL$instance (sql server service user)
  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219062.aspx)
- Giving all other roles to user(login) except sysadmin
- Giving all permissions to user(login)

Want to do following things without any restriction with non-sysadmin role

- Backup- restore
- Attach - detach
- Create new db etc

Comment: Even though when we type the path of backup by manually after error message it works, but for attach/detach operations it does not work, need to find out accessing file system by a login which is non-sysadmin